# Saving / exporting transformed DataFrame back to JDBC / MySQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.5

I'm trying to figure out how to use the new `DataFrameWriter` to write data back to a JDBC database. I can't seem to find any documentation for this, although looking at the source code it seems like it should be possible.

A trivial example of what I'm trying looks like this:

```
sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:mysql://localhost/foo", "dbtable" -> "foo.bar")
).select("some_column", "another_column")
.write.format("jdbc").options(Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:mysql://localhost/foo", "dbtable" -> "foo.bar2")
).save("foo.bar2")
```

This doesn't work — I end up with this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource does not allow create table as select.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:200)
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong (why is it resolving to DefaultSource instead of JDBCRDD for example?) or if writing to an existing MySQL database just isn't possible using Spark's DataFrames API.

Comment: It is not the source of the problem but your example is missing `load` call.

Answer (score 8):

**Update**

Current Spark version (2.0 or later) supports table creation on write.

**The original answer**

It is possible to write to an existing table but it looks like at this moment (Spark 1.5.0) creating table using JDBC data source is not supported yet*. You can check [SPARK-7646](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7646) for reference.

If table already exists you can simply use `DataFrameWriter.jdbc` method:

```
val prop: java.util.Properties = ???
df.write.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost/foo", "foo.bar2", prop)
```

* What is interesting PySpark seems to support table creation using `jdbc` method.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly with the addition of a save mode; i.e. `df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost/foo", "foo.bar2", prop)`